# Check/uncheck checkbox depend on data come from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, setattribute

I am trying to check or uncheck a checkbox depending on the data from mysql database. I use nusoap webservice/webclient to read data and data value can be 1 or 0.

My code is:

```
<input name="check1" type="checkbox" id="check1" class="sag">
<script>
    function control() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data: {
                checkdata: 1
            },
            success: function(asd) {
                if (asd == '1') {
                    document.getElementById('check1').setAttribute("checked", true);


                    alert('data is 1');

                } else {
                    document.getElementById('check1').removeAttribute("checked");

                    alert('data is 0');
                }
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<body onload="control()">
```

With this code i can get data from database correctly and alert() works fine. But these codes don't add checked attribute to checkbox. How can i change check status of checkbox according to the data come from database on load of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure if you just copied and pasted this but right now its invalid HTML as your body tag should be before all content, but in this case you have an input above it.

Comment: you can simply do $('check1').attr('checked', true);

Comment: it is not copied. Body tag is on the top of the body content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using `jQuery` why don't you use `jQuery` methods to set the required values.

```
function control(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "check.php",
          data: {checkdata: 1},
          success: function(asd){
             $('#check1').prop("checked", asd == '1');
          }
      });

  }
```

Comment: I think it's clearer to use the value 'true' as opposed to an expression that evaluates to true for the second argument in prop(), that way the user can reuse that bit of code easily later on.  Like this: $('#check1').prop('checked', true);

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not that familiar to jquery and still using old fashioned javascript. This solved my problem but i found that main problem is Ios style checkbox that made with jquery. Checkbox checks correctly but style still shows off.

Comment: If you are using any checkbox plugin then try to trigger the `change` event after you change the value. E.g `$('#check1').prop('checked', true).trigger('change')`, May be plugin is listening to the change event and it will update it's UI accordingly.